# Keep records that match variable length codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

This problem originated from working with ICD-9 and ICD-10 classification codes.

> Given a set of code prefixes of variable length, return all records from a table that match these codes. Assume the list of codes is long enough that it is stored in a lookup table.

For example:

```sql
code_prefixes char_length
   A12          3
   B123         4
```

My naive approach was to use `SUBSTRING` and list each different length as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM main_table
WHERE SUBSTRING(code, 1, 3) IN (SELECT code_prefix FROM lookup_table WHERE char_length = 3)
OR SUBSTRING(code, 1, 4) IN (SELECT code_prefix FROM lookup_table WHERE char_length = 4)
```

But this requires duplication for every different length value in `code_prefix` and it assumes that `char_length` is always correct.

Comment: Is there any overlap between the 3 and 4 character codes? E.g., you don't have both "A12" and "A123"?

Comment: There could be. The solution needs to be flexible enough to handle this.

Comment: I suspect you might have larger issues downstream of this process. Just knowing a "random" string contains a valid ICD code (but not which one) seems like an odd goal. But the solution you have is precise and one I find preferable to using the LIKE approach. Test all and decide yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `LIKE` in an `EXISTS` subquery

```sql
SELECT *
FROM main_table AS M
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM lookup_table AS L
    WHERE M.code LIKE L.code_prefix + '%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I have come up with so far:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM main_table AS M
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM lookup_table AS L
    WHERE SUBSTRING(M.code, 1, LEN(L.code_prefix)) = L.code_prefix
)
```